# how to select first radio button without knowing the value using vue.js (and v-model)

Tags: vue.js

In my use case the radio buttons is initially dynamically rendered by server. Then in client side I want to use `v-model` to handle the value change and related logic. The problem is that I want to pre-select the first button but in client side I don't know the value of it. What is the recommended way to do this in vue.js? If necessary the server can generate some "hint" for it.

I've been searching for a while but every working solution I saw assume the data is already there. One method I can think of is to make an api to return the buttons' value but this feels overkill.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vm77frtg/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the initial value of `r` in the `mounted` hook of the component to the value of the first radio button:

```
mounted() {
  this.r = this.$el.querySelector('input[type="radio"]').value;
}
```

But it might be better to use a fixed template for the component that isn't rendered by the server in the first place. Instead of rendering HTML, you could render JavaScript containing the data for the items you want and then bind that data to the template.

Vue works best when the template is generated from the data instead of the other way around.

```
<script>
  // Rendered by the server external to the Vue component,
  // otherwise just render directly into the component's data
  window.items = [
    { label: 'Apple', value: 'apple' },
    { label: 'Orange', value: 'orange' },
  ];
</script>
```

```
<label>
  <input v-model="selected" v-for="item of items" type="radio" :value="item.value">
  {{ item.label }}
</label>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: window.items,
    selected: window.items[0].value,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you. For now I will just use the mounted approach.